# Why Does Xcode Show "Ambiguous use of 'myMethod' When Implementing Fallback Using @available?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In implementing fallback instance methods for methods using `@available(iOS 8.0, *)`, Xcode shows a built error:

`"Ambiguous use of 'myMethod'...`

along with two candidate methods highlighted.

This is despite using the `@available` directive.

For example:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func getURLParameter() -> NSURLQueryItem 
{
   return NSURLQueryItem(name: "name", value: "John")
}

func getURLParameter() -> Dictionary<String, String>
{
   return ["name" : "John"]
}

let param = getURLParameter()
```

The `@available` works successfully elsewhere with methods identically named. Why does it fail in this case?

Comment: Above or equal to iOS 8, both `getURLParameter` methods are available and when you declare `let param` without type, the compiler probably doesn't know which method to use. However you mentioned that it works with other cases, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Self answering question this one in case it should help others. You're absolutely on the right lines. Elsewhere the variable in the declaration was  specified, i.e.  let param:NSURLQueryItem =

Comment: ps. feel free to put in a decent answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above or equal to iOS 8, both `getURLParameter` methods are available, and if you declare your `param` variable without type, the compiler will not be able the choose between the methods.